# UITableView with single row display - How to move another row to display area with animation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to make a menu for my app like bottom menu of Camera+ app in itunes: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id329670577?mt=8 (pic 2).
This is a review, at 5 minutes 17 seconds : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNJzhyb7mNI#t=5m17s

I custom UITableViewCell to make a row contain array of buttons with horizontal scroll. Then I create a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell for menus. 
My question: How to change another row to visible area with animation like menu of Camera+.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution:
I create 1 `NSArray*` to contain current menu name is: `menuDataSource`. `menuDataSource` only contain current menu.

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
return [menuDataSource objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

When user change menu, I recreate menuDataSource with new menu:

```
[internalTableView beginUpdates];
currentHorizonMenu = [[self.reusableCells objectAtIndex:menuIndex]retain];
menuDataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
[internalTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[menuDataSource addObject:currentHorizonMenu];
[internalTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];        
[internalTableView endUpdates];
```

`self.reusableCells` is `NSArray*` contain all menus

Answer (score 0):

Send `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` to your table view.  Something along the lines of this:

```
[self.menuTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath
    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
    animated:YES];
```

Comment: But it has a crash when i try to scroll from last index of table to top .And effect doesn't seem like Camera+. But now I found a solution! Once again, thank you very much!